# Update null values by merging another table in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sql-update

I have two tables like :

Table 1:

```
Customer    employee
ASD_1234    WF001
ASD_1235    WF002
ASD_1236    WF003
ASD_1237    NULL
ASD_1238    NULL
ASD_1239    NULL
ASD_1240    WF004
ASD_1234    WF001
ASD_1236    WF003
ASD_1240    WF004
```

Table2:

```
Customer    com_employee
ASD_1234    WF001
ASD_1235    WF002
ASD_1236    WF003
ASD_1237    WF005
ASD_1238    WF006
ASD_1239    WF007
ASD_1240    WF004
```

The table 2 is the metadata which consists of unique **Customer**.Now I need to update **only the null values** in table1 by joining table2 on Customer. How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET employee = (
    SELECT com_employee
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.customer = table1.customer
)
WHERE employee IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an update-join statement with a condition on the nullibility of the `employee`:

```
UPDATE t1
SET    t1.employee = t2.com_employee
FROM   t1
JOIN   t2 ON t1.customer = t2.customer
WHERE  t1.employee IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using an updatable CTE here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.employee, t2.com_employee
    FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2
        ON t1.Customer = t2.Customer
)

UPDATE cte
SET employee = com_employee
WHERE employee IS NULL;
```